# Cannot install PHP CURL, php5-common discrepency

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, dependencies

When every I try to install `php5-curl`, `php5-common`, `php5` I always get following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    php5-curl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`
```

I've tried every suggestion, including clean, remove, update. I can't reinstall or start a new instance. Any suggestions?

```
System information as of Tue Sep  3 04:50:44 UTC 2013

System load:  0.0               Processes:           72
Usage of /:   5.4% of 98.52GB   Users logged in:     1
Memory usage: 61%               IP address for eth0: 10.184.33.3
Swap usage:   0%

Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-29-virtual x86_64)
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: And the output of `apt-cache policy php5-curl php5-common php5`.

Comment: Note: The error data from `apt-get` suggests that `php5-curl` is not as up to date as `php5`/`php5-common` is.  (differing versions)

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the best solution for you**

I always use **Synaptic Package Manager** to fix such issues. Using it you can **forcefully** install other version of packages.

- Fist install synaptic package manager if you don't have already installed:

  ```
   $ sudo apt-get install synaptic
  ```
- Then open synaptic package manager -> click **Custom Filters** down-left -> click **Broken** top-left, it will list all broken packages(*if you have, other wise it will show nothing*) try to fix all broken packages. Also if any residual packages are there on more option you will get as **residual packages**.
- Search for packages you want to **downgrade/upgrade**, highlight it by simply clicking on it **do not mark(tick)**, chose **Package** from the menu -> **Force Version** and chose some other versions from the list. Then click **Apply** to downgrade/upgrade it. (*You may also get that the selected package depends some other package, then search for that package and repeat this step till you fix all*)
- now try to install your actually packages, it would install without any problem.
- You can get more help about [How to use Synaptic Package Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto)

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt-get -f install`, as the error message suggests.

Comment: Already have, no dice.