# Intel Haswell strange graphics and boot issue

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, lightdm

I build a new system with a Core i5-4570S CPU and I use the internal graphics card.

I can Install Ubuntu 13.04 without problem and everything seems to work fine, but during boot and when I turn the PC off I see some really strange colors on the screen, kind of blue and the colors seem to be moving.

Do I have to worry about this? Once I am in the Unity/Gnome Desktop this does not occur.

The card seem to be recognised:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

I am using this kernel:

```
3.8.0-30-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 20:52:24 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The second problem just came up. I did an update today, there was a new kernel.
After this update the machine does not show the lightdm login screen, just a blinking cursor. When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and restart `lightdm` it gives me the login screen.

What can I do? Do you need more info?

Comment: VTC'd as EOL specific since kernel upgrades since 13.04 should fix any Haswell related problems.

Answer (score 1):

**Last Option that you can give a try**

- Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute these commands:

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.back
  ```

  if this command says `file not available` then not a problem. Proceed further..

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
  ```

  when editor opens copy following code and paste on the editor:

  ```
  Section "Device"
  Identifier "Configured Video Device"
  Driver "intel"
  EndSection

  Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Configured Monitor"
  EndSection

  Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Default Screen"
  Monitor "Configured Monitor"
  Device "Configured Video Device"
  EndSection
  ```

  Save(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and close(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) and execute following:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}'|grep "^xserver"|tr '\n' ' ')

  sudo update-initramfs -u
  ```
- Then finally restart your computer.

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

Hope this last option works for you.. If you get any time of error, just remove `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file and restart your system again.

Comment: sorry, still the same. would a kernel update help, maybe? is it safe to do this? http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/kernel-3-10-4-is-ready-install-upgrade-in-ubuntu-13-04-12-14/

Comment: Did you get any error at any stage of the procedure?

Comment: no i did not see any errors

Comment: Yes, you can any new kernel you want.. [Read My Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340745/should-i-allow-kernel-updates/340751#340751) for more information of Kernel Update.

Comment: k, i try that after work. can I just use the latest version? http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/current/

Comment: Yes of course you can install and use it.. But do you know how to install?

Comment: yes, i think i just download the x64 .debs and install them, right?

Comment: No not that way simply.. you have to download others packages which was for x64. The link that I recommended you has all the information. if you don't get it then I can explain it again..

Comment: mmh, sad that there isnt an repo which i could just add to my sources. but your link says that i should download the debs and install them: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Installing_Mainline_Kernels . Do i have to take care to use a kernel that has "raring" in its name? so the latest would be from April?

Comment: You give a try to latest kernel without any worry.. If some error occurs you can simply remove it.. So don't worry.. Give it a try..

Comment: ill do after work. what is causing these strange graphics? should I contact intel or is it an ubuntu specific problem?

Comment: It's not any specific problem.. Its graphics driver problem.. Some time some kernel doesn't match with graphics drivers. Same happened with me once, but using Kernel 3.8.x with xserver-xorg drivers for -lts-raring solved my issue and its running like a charm..

Comment: ic, one thing i dont get is that your package is called xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-raring, but my are only xserver-xorg-video-intel

Comment: k, back home. i did install the 3.11 and the problem is still there. can i maybe that the logoutprogressscreen has the wrong resolution or something?

Comment: ok  I did install a different plymouth theme and now it shows me the progress bar during reboot and not that strange one i posted. i also did uninstall all the other kernels, or should I stick with the 3.11?

Comment: If 3.11 is working fine then no problem.. That good to use `latest kernel`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be your `graphics` card problem. The `graphics card driver` doesn't match with your newest kernel. Give it a try first, if it doesn't work then I will suggest you to install latest graphics card driver:

**Try to reconfigure lightdm, it may fix your issue**

- When blank screen appears the press<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to `tty1`, login and execute following commands:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigre lightdm
  ```
- Then chose `lightdm` from the list.
- Restart your system:

  ```
  sudo reboot now
  ```

It may fix your issue. If doesn't fix then follow *2nd Method*.

**Method 2:**

Installing a new display manager can fix your problem. Steps to install **GDM**(a display manager much like *lightdm*):

- Again when black screen appears <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then login and execute following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gdm
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```

  then chose `gdm` from the list. And restart your system:

  ```
  sudo reboot now
  ```

---

Installing/Updating `Latest graphics driver for Intel`

- Open a terminal and execute following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install intel-linux-graphics-installer
  ```

  if it says something: `package not found` then go to **Update** section below and execute this command again.
- Once installed open it from `dash` and follow on screen instruction to update your graphics driver.
- Thats all. It would update/install your graphics driver to a newer version.

**Update:**

Run these commands to get latest version of `Intel-Linux-Graphics-Installer`

```
    wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \

    sudo apt-key add -


    wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | \

    sudo apt-key add -

    sudo apt-get update
```

Hope these methods solve your issue. Reply for further assistance.

Comment: Hello,

that did fix the loginscreen problem. big thnx
How can I update the graphicscard driver?
Do I have to install a new kernel, what is the safest way to get a new kernel?

greetings

Comment: Sounds good.. Since you are using `Ubuntu 13.04` you can use `Intel-Linux-Graphics-Installer` a software from `Intel` which updates your `Intel Graphics Driver` very easily. I am editing my answer and describing how can you install.. Once it solves your issue, just mark my answer as solved so that it would help others to find their solution.

Comment: check for my answer.. Reply if something goes wrong.

Comment: Hello, i got a bit experimental and just downloaded the latest version from 01.org because i couldnt find that pacakge. It seems to work fine, i have to do a second reboot. do I have to add a extra repo for this package? I still have these strange graphics while reboot/shutdown :(.

Comment: I didn't get you? What did you download `Intel-Linux-Graphics-Installer` .deb file? Did you follow my steps precisely? Did you follow the steps in **Update** section?

Comment: yes I did: apt-get install intel-linux-graphics-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
intel-linux-graphics-installer is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
I did run the programm and installed the latest drivers, but i still have this strange blue screen during reboot/shutdowns.

Comment: Can you provide some pictures, of you problem? then only it can be understood easily. Look at your question page how to attach a picture link.

Comment: sorry, but i dont have enough reputations, so i can post a pictures. please look at this link: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0QD0SWw2o_wY3hVNTUyWlk5aEU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, I saw that.. So you are using `Kernel 3.8.0.30` then execute this command, do not press `y`, just execute and tell me what does it say: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-raring`

Comment: that didnt work: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-raring but in synaptic i see the following when i search for  xserver-xorg-video-intel: installed version 2:2.21.9-0ubuntu0~raring

Comment: Good you replied the version of xserver-xorg-video-intel in advanced, and also mentioned that you are familiar about `Synaptic package manager`. Now in `Synaptic` do you know how to install forcefully any package?

Comment: Hello, nope i dont. please post me the steps. i have to do them tommorow its getting late... what do I have to do?

Comment: I had mentioned this as an answer in [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340723/cannot-install-php-curl-php5-common-discrepency/340740#340740) post. Go for `third point` to get this. I have also mentioned a good link for how to use `Synaptic`

Comment: Actually you have to forcefully install `xserver-xorg-video-intel` driver using that way.. Hope you can understand further..

Comment: sorry, but the driver xserver-xorg-video-intel is already installed. It is the version from 01.org.

Comment: Did you try to `Force Install` as mentioned in my link. You can also [go here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) for more help regarding `Synaptic Package Manager`. Look for topic `Force Installation`

Comment: sorry, but I dont get it. the xserver-xorg-video-intel is installed.Do you mean I should reinstall the latest version?

Comment: no you have already new version installed.. You have to install previous version, that's the problem.. Give me your email id I'll send previous version you just give that a try..

Comment: mh, can i PM you? there are 2 other versions in the repos:2.21-6-0ubuntu4.1 and 2.21-6-0ubuntu4. The Problem is there from the beginning, so I dont think downgrading would help

Comment: Give it a try.. That is what I was expecting from you.. Downgrade it once.. If that doesn't solve then I'll suggest you another way..

Comment: OK. i did install the older version. did not help, still this strange screen.

Comment: did you restart your system?

Comment: yes, twice i did

Comment: hmm.. Then I have to suggest the last option to you.. I have to right that as an answer.. Give me some time.